# Two different colors in the same text by using html and css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to set two different colors to my text . My text is phrase 1 / phrase2 and i want to set black color to phrase 1 / and green color to phrase2

```
<label class="diffcolor">pharse1/ phrase2</label>
```

My example

```
<label class="diffcolor">pharse1/ </label>
```

css:

```
.different::after{
    color : green;
    content :"phrase2";
}
```

I doesn't work to my internet explorer browser. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3):

```css
label.class { color:#4C4C4C }
span.name { color:#FF0000; }
```

```html
<label class="diffcolor">pharse1/ <span class="name">phrase2</span></label>
```